# Phase relationship of multiple Fractional-N PLLs with same reference clock

Tags: clock, pll, phase, phase-shift, vco

I *think* I understand the general operation of PLLs in the case where a single reference clock generates a single output clock. Once the PLL is locked, there is a deterministic relationship between the input and output clock frequency and phase. I understand the negative feedback loop, VCO, etc. However, I am uncertain about the theory of how PLLs behave when they are separated into physical components on a PCB.

After reading [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138159/will-two-plls-wander-with-shared-reference-clock) question, I still am uncertain how fractional PLLs behave with lower output frequency than the reference.

**Question**

If I configure 2 separate (but identical) PLLs on a PCB such that:

- I supply the same 10MHz reference clock to both PLLs
- I control the nets on the PCB to be identical length, width, ground plane coverage, etc.
- I configure the PLLs "identically"

After both PLLs are locked (Fout1=Fout2), will the signals Fout1 and Fout2:

- Be identical in **phase** if Fout > Fin and the relationship is a fractional multiple?
- Be identical in **phase** if Fout < Fin and the relationship is a fractional multiple?

In other words, is both the rising and falling edge of Fout1 aligned to the rising and falling edge of Fout2?

[image: pll]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranteed phase relationship, except that it should be stable once locked.

To synchronise the outputs of Fractional-N PLLs, you need to synchronise the sigma-delta modulators. If the reference frequency is low enough, and you power them up and program them at the same time, then they may reliably start in sync, but I don't know how you guarantee it.

Various manufacturers have ways of doing this,  here is a random document I found on the ADI site:
[phase-resync-phase-programmability-and-phase-coherence-between-multiple-fractional-n-plls](https://ez.analog.com/rf/w/documents/9662/phase-resync-phase-programmability-and-phase-coherence-between-multiple-fractional-n-plls)

Comment: Ah yes, phase coherence is the exact term I was looking for! With a purely integer PLL, this is much more straightforward. Thanks, Tesla. This is definitely points me on the right path.